# Does any home media release of "The Office" (US) include longer version of episodes with deleted scenes?

Tags: the-office, distribution

I've recently discovered a whole cache of episode-wise deleted scene videos of The Office on YouTube. I only assume it came from the bonus features on the DVDs. This is somewhat unusual, because generally the deleted scenes of sitcoms are edited season-wise, out of order.

This made me think of an earlier NBC sitcom—*Friends*—which had longer episodes on some of its DVD releases. The longer cuts restored the deleted scenes into the narrative, making some episodes much better.*

I wonder if NBC did something similar for The Office, considering that these deleted scenes are arranged almost chronologically and add anywhere from 5 to 15 minutes to the episodes. Seems like a good opportunity to give it the "Friends" treatment. Yet, the [home media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Office_(U.S._TV_series)#Home_media) section of The Office's Wikipedia page offers no clues. Neither does a Google search.

So, my question is:
Is there a version of Office episodes, for any season, which incorporates deleted scenes into the aired version of the episodes? Whether released officially or unofficially; in DVD, Blu-Ray or digital media?

To be clear, I'm talking about extended cuts of the main episodes themselves, not the deleted scenes as an separate extra feature.

<sup>*[The best example I can think of is the famous "Pivot" episode. The aired cut never showed how the couch got torn in half in the closing scene. The extended DVD cut shows that Chandler accidentally set off the fire alarm while moving, causing the building-ful of people jumping on and over the couch to escape, thus ruining it.]</sup>

Comment: I have a link to a Google Drive where some guy edited in those deleted scenes into each episode. Let me dig for it

Comment: Not that I can find - http://www.dvdcompare.net/comparisons/film.php?fid=9623

Comment: Looks like no but [amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Office-Complete-Steve-Carell/dp/B00LTO342M) is selling full show with deleted scenes  in the pack